# Calling PowerShell script from .bat file

Tags: powershell

I have a .bat as shown below

```
@echo off
powershell "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\Output\Test_Eamil.ps1" > "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\logs\test.log"
pause
```

But its not showing any log in the output,i intenationaly kept some error in the script.Could you help me to solve this.

Comment: I think that it might be an error in your test_email.ps1, can you add that to your question?

Comment: Also, does the script produce any output if you remove the redirection?

Comment: If i remove redirection it will generate output